# Optical Isomerism in Coordination Compounds of type MA₂B₂(CC)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stereochemistry, coordination-compounds

I was asked the following question:

> How many optical isomers are there for $\ce{[Cr(NH3)2Cl2(en)]^+}$ ?

First of all I figured out the following four *geometrical isomers* of the above complex:

[image: geometrical isomers of Cr(NH3)2Cl2(en)+]

Out of which, (*iii*) and (*iv*) are optically inactive, due to a *plane of symmetry* (shown by faint line) passing through them as shown below:

[image: visualisation of the plane of symmetry]

For (*iii*), you can suppose: green as $\ce{en}$, orange as $\ce{NH3}$ and red as $\ce{Cl}$. Similarly, for (*iv*), you can suppose: green as $\ce{en}$, orange as $\ce{Cl}$ and red as $\ce{NH3}$.
Therefore only (*i*) and (*ii*) *will show optical isomerism*, which I've confirmed myself.

---

But, the following four isomers was provided as answer, in which I don't think that the second configuration of complex will show any optical activity due to plane of symmetry (as discussed above for the (*iv*) geometrical isomer).

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's you who's doing wrong.

Comment: Well, it's a valid mirror plane. It's just that it's the same compound after mirroring...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came to the same conclusion as you, total **4** stereoisomers (2 of them create one enantiomeric pair).

In the 3rd party solution, they depict the same isomer at bottom, i.e. only 3. The missing one is that with two $\ce{NH3}$ ligands in the same plane with $en$, and $\ce{Cl-}$ ligands in straight line (trans), perpendicular to that plane (not that horizontal, which is depicted)

[image: Fig.0]

Here is my simplified schematic representation of the octahedral complex with ethylenediamine ligand bound by back-pointing bonds in horizontal plane, hidden; the rest is vertical axis and two front-pointing horizontal bonds (seesaw geometry, not to be confused with Fischer projection for tetrahedrals!) Dotted line is mirror plane, equal sign means identity (by 180° rotation around observer-to-model-line axis).

[image: Fig.1]
[image: Fig.2]

1. has B ligands in the *(en)*-defined plane, A ligands perpendicular (axis)
   (it's their bottom left isomer, idenitical with bottom right, for A=$\ce{NH3}$, B=$\ce{Cl}$; note that they have *en* oriented vertically, everywhere, with one end in dotted horizontal plane, other one in upper vertical position, I have it somewhat simpler, rotated for *en* to be horizontal);
2. has the opposite, A's and B's swapped (and it's not mirror image to 1.)
   (it's their missing isomer);

If A and B are in the plane then there are two possibilities how to relatively place A and B in the perpendicular axis (resulting in mirror images),

3. (it's their top right);
4. (it's their top left).

Comment: _If the claimed 3rd party correct solution image you provided is complete_ - Yes, [the solution](http://www.saralstudy.com/study-eschool-ncertsolution/chemistry/coordination-compounds/1936-draw-the-structures-of-optical-isomers-of-i) is complete.

Comment: @rv7 OK, I did not want to visit unknown sites. Well, you have apparently posted someone's complete solution, that is unfortunately incomplete :)